# Работа над строками в С++

Tags: c++

Мне нужно выделить подстроку, которая соответствует записи вещественного числа с фиксированной и плавующей точкой.

```
for (i = 0; i <= k; i++)
{
    if ((st1[i] >= '0') && (st1[i] <= '9'))
    {
        t = atof(&st1[i]);
        gcvt(t, 10, st2);
        cout << t << " ";
        l = strlen(st2);
        i = i+l;
    }
}
```

У меня только выделяет фиксированную точку!!! что дополнить нужно!!! заранее спасибо!!

Answer (score 2):

Судя по написанному, Вы НЕ ВЫДЕЛЯЕТЕ ПОДСТРОКУ, а пытаетесь применить такой "хак" - преобразуете строку в число и обратно. Почему бы Вам не написать код, который действительно будет выделять подстроку?, например так:

```
bool waspoint = false;
int ndigits = 0;

char str2[250];

for(int i=0; i <= k; ++i)
{
  // проверим, если символ допустим для числа
  if((str1[i] >= '0' && str1[i] <= '9') || (str1[i] == '.' && !waspoint))
  {
    // если точка, - установим флаг
    if(str1[i] == '.') waspoint = true;
    // добавим "цифру" к числу
    str2[ndigits++] = str1[i];
    str2[ndigits] = 0;
  } 
  else // недопустимый символ, проверим, если было введено ранее несколько знаков числа
  {
    if(ndigits > 0 && !(ndigits == 1 && str2[0] == '.')) // одиночная точка - не число
    {
      // выведем число
      cout << str2 << " "; // или cout << atof(str2) << " ";
    }
    // обнулим флаг и число цифр
    waspoint = false;
    ndigits = 0;
    // проверим, если недопустимый символ - новая точка, внесем ее как новый символ в число
    if(str1[i] == '.')
    {
      waspoint = true;
      // добавим "цифру" к числу
      str2[ndigits++] = str1[i];
      str2[ndigits] = 0;
    } 
  }
}
```

конечно, данная реализация не понимает записей со знаком, так же как и записей с E. Но, основываясь на ней, можно сделать и эти записи допустимыми. Фактически, мы описываем конечный автомат.... Лучше всего (на мой взгляд) подойти к этому вопросу системно, и определить, какие виды записей будут поддерживаться ну и т.д...

Comment: Т.е. для тренировки реализовать подобие strtod(). Желательно не забыть определить OVERFLOW и UNDERFLOW.

Answer (score 1):

Вашу реализацию не понимаю.

Думаю Вам надо посмотреть на функции strtod() для выявления чисел (в т.ч. их размещения в символах строки).

Кстати, число может начинаться с знака, а также с точки, например .55 или даже -.89e3

Answer (score 0):

Положительные целые/дробные числа ( без экспоненциальной формы ).

( Не факт что без ошибок и слегка не завершенное ) :

```
char *arr;
int k,
    i,
    first = 0,
    second = 0;

for ( i = 0; i <= k && arr[i] >= '0' && arr[i] <= '9'; i++ ){}
first = i;

if ( arr[i] == '.' ){
  for ( i = i + 1; i <= k && arr[i] >= '0' && arr[i] <= '9'; i++ ){}
  second = i;
}

if ( first != k ) arr[ first ] = 0;
first = atoi( arr );

if ( second != 0 ){
  if ( second != k ) arr[ second ] = 0;
  second = atoi( arr[ first + 1 ] );
}
```